# Using a global_work_offset in clEnqueueNDRangeKernel

Tags: opencl

I have a global work size of 1000 but i want only to execute the kernel from 200 to 1000.

```
size_t global_work_size = 1000;
size_t global_work_offset = 200;
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cpu_queue, kernel [0], 1, &global_work_offset, &global_work_size, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

The problem is it does compute the whole 0-1000 range even if I specify an offset. I tried using:

```
size_t global_work_offset [1] = {200}; but still no luck.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should notice the difference between that parameter in CL 1.0 and 1.1:

CL 1.0:

> global_work_offset
>       Must currently be a NULL value. In a future revision of OpenCL,
>   global_work_offset can be used to specify an array of work_dim
>   unsigned values that describe the offset used to calculate the global
>   ID of a work-item instead of having the global IDs always start at
>   offset (0, 0,... 0).

CL 1.1:

> global_work_offset
>       global_work_offset can be used to specify an array of work_dim
>   unsigned values that describe the offset used to calculate the global
>   ID of a work-item. If global_work_offset is NULL, the global IDs start
>   at offset (0, 0, ... 0).

So, check that you have a CL 1.1 device and drivers.